# Writing a video chat widget in Flash and PHP

Tags: php, linux, flash, adobe, webcam

I am writing a webcam chat in flash (for the client side), I also am using PHP/Apache/Memcache for the server side for text chats... What exactly will I need in terms of server side software to connect these users flash/swf sessions together?

I currently have an ubuntu server running Lamp (Apache/Php/MySql/Memcache)... the client to client text chatting works fine, just need to somehow connect the webcams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe has a beta product called Stratus which allows p2p RTMP between flash clients with minimal server involvement. It's a beta product and the TOS specify non-commercial use, but you can try it out. http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/stratus/

If for whatever reason Stratus won't work for you, you will need a Flash Media Server or clone to connect the clients: http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/

Comment: An open source alternative to Adobe's Flash Media Server is Red5 http://www.red5.org/

Comment: I have yet to set it up, but I'm told that with the tutorials they have you can set up a multiuser video chat session in like 20 minutes with Adobe Stratus.